# Not in List Error after replacing Chr(), yet added to list correctly

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some combo boxes with code for adding new items to the source table with a form when it doesn't exist.

The code will replace Chr(47) / and Chr(92) \ with Chr(45) - if present. This is done because a file name is created using concatenation later.

The problem is if a character is replaced, I get an Access error that the item is not in the list. This does not happen if a character is not replaced. In both instances the correct items are added to the corresponding tables.

I have tried replacing the character before passing it to OpenArgs, AfterUpdate, on the form after it opens, etc. The error does not break so the program is working, I just want to eliminate a unnecessary pop-up message.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cboManual_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    Dim MyMessage As String
    Dim myButtons As Integer
    Dim myTitle As String
    Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

MyMessage = "This Manual does not exist. Create it?"
myButtons = vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1 + vbQuestion + vbApplicationModal
myTitle = "Add Manual?"
MyChoice = MsgBox(MyMessage, myButtons, myTitle)

If MyChoice = 6 Then
    If Not DBAuthority = "Admin" And Not DBAuthority = "Data Entry" Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        MsgBox "Sorry, authorized access only", _
               vbOKOnly, "Important Information"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Response = acDataErrAdded
        CallerField = "Manual"
        CallerForm = "NewDocument"
        NewData = Replace(NewData, Chr(47), Chr(45))
        NewData = Replace(NewData, Chr(92), Chr(45))
        DoCmd.OpenForm "AddManual", windowmode:=acDialog, OpenArgs:=NewData
        Me.cboManual.RowSource = Me.cboManual.RowSource
        Me.cboManual.value = strAddManual
        strManual = Me.cboManual.value
        strAddManual = vbNullString
        Me.cboSection.value = strAddSection
        strSection = Me.cboSection.value
        strAddSection = vbNullString
        Me.cboEngine.value = strAddEngine
        strEngine = Me.cboEngine.value
        strAddEngine = vbNullString
    End If
ElseIf MyChoice = 7 Then
    Response = acDataErrContinue
    MsgBox "Select Manual from list.", vbOKOnly, "Select Manual"
    Me.cboManual.Undo
    Me.cboManual.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err = 20 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    ElseIf Err = 94 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        Resume Next
    ElseIf Err = 2237 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        Resume Next
    ElseIf Err = 0 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    Else
        MsgBox "cboManual.NotInList Err = " & Err.Number & " :" &     Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't modify the new data. You should probably use keyDown event and replace while typed.

Comment: @krish KM: I have a KeyDown event that will expand the dropdown menu if the down arrow is used. Would I be better off adding in an ElseIf or maybe a KeyPress Event? What would use less resources?

Comment: use select case in keydown event and do the replacements.

Comment: @krish KM: I'm sorry, I'm completely self taught and have never used that before. Could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option one**
Replace while typing

```
Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyDown
            Me![cboNewPart].Dropdown
        Case 220, 191 ' / and \
            KeyCode = 189 ' with -
        Case Else
    End Select
```

**Option two**
after adding the new value to the table. do

```
me.combo.undo, me.combo.requery. me.combo.value = newValue
```

followed by acDataErrContinue
this way you won't get error message but the list will flicker a and it's purely a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different variable name (other than `NewData`) to store the modified version of the value passed to the `NewData` argument, i.e.:

```
Dim NewString as String
NewString = NewData
NewString = Replace(NewString, Chr(47), Chr(45))
NewString = Replace(NewString, Chr(92), Chr(45))
DoCmd.OpenForm "AddManual", windowmode:=acDialog, OpenArgs:=NewString
```

Since VBA arguments are passed `ByRef` unless otherwise stated, any modification to the argument value will be modifying the original value passed to your `cboManual_NotInList` event handler.

---

Given the above, you could alternatively try changing the `NewData` argument to be passed by value (`ByVal`):

```
Private Sub cboManual_NotInList(ByVal NewData As String, Response As Integer)
```

Comment: Unfortunately same result. Error if a character is replaced, no error when there are no characters replaced. Both are still added correctly though.

Comment: Does the error give any indication of the VBA expression which is causing it?

Comment: No. It's just a generic Access message. How can I add a screen shot here?

Comment: @DyannaM: You can copy the content (the text) of an Access error message to the clipboard by pressing `Ctrl-c` when it's shown and then past the relevant part here. That applies for simple `MsgBox`s too.

Comment: I add in the ByVal and get an error when loading the form.

The expression On Load you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

Comment: @Unhandled Exception: I'm unable to get it with a simple Crt+C
I have it on the clipboard from the Snipping Tool but it won't let me attach it here.

Comment: @DyannaM: Oh, you are right. I should have checked this before. I was quite sure, that this works with Access error messages too and not only with `MsgBox`s. Sorry.